# Angular File Upload Application/Octet-Stream

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

Is it possible to upload files as octet-stream with the angular file upload plugin?
I manually set the content-type in the header to "application/octet-stream", but the uploader doesn't validate it's own headers.

The body always is form-data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGgizqnvAqFRXn2HB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="53f60e5267c2460000623dcd.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav


------WebKitFormBoundaryGgizqnvAqFRXn2HB--
```

Is there a possibility to set the upload to octet-stream?
The server I'm uploading to doesn't support form-data.